# Query regarding Facebook Places Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'am using graph API in my application. Recently I have come up with a trouble retrieving places using Places API.

When I try to retrieve locations using places API I'm not getting response as expected, please let me know in case if I'm missing out some steps.

url used in app is:-

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Paris%2c%20France&type=place&center=48.8567,2.3508&limit=20&distance=100

What is the minimum value of the distance to be specified?
As I'm able to get more places if I increase distance value from 100 to 1000

Answer (score 1):

Playing with the [Graph API explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search?q=Paris,France&type=place&center=48.8567,2.3508&limit=20&distance=1), there doesnt seem any specific value that can be used as `minimum value` while querying. Since using specifying `1` I still seem to be able to fetch the results, as of now the maximum value that you can specify seems to be `50000m` for `place queries`.

Comment: You might want to accept the answer if you found it useful :)

Comment: Actually problem is with limit parameter, it seems limit parameter does not return expected value.If i give limit value as 4 i'am able to get single location value(as response) but if i give limit value as 20,location value is being received as response is 17.As per my project requirements i need to restrict the location value based on limit parameter.Is this a Facebook bug?

Comment: well it does seem to be a facebook bug!